# Is it possible to filter SPSiteDataQuery results by site?

Tags: spsitedataquery

I'm using [SPSiteDataQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.aspx) to query several lists in different sites. Unfortunately, I don't want the data from all of these sites; I have a list of ones to include and exclude.

So far I've seen [SPSiteDataQuery.Webs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.webs.aspx) which seems to only allow the scope to be changed (entire collection, just subsites, just this site), and [SPSiteDataQuery. Lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.lists.aspx) which would require the List IDs (that I don't have) or the lists' template IDs (not specific enough).

How do I persuade SPSiteDataQuery to only return results for the sites on my include list?  FYI: I have the IDs and URLs of the sites to include, and filtering post-fetch is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this without some form of filtering post fetch. However, it isn't hard.

SPSiteDataQuery queries automatically include DataColumns in the DataTable for `ListId` and `WebId`, so you could *then* filter your DataTable by Web. I know it's not idea - 'query and filter', rather than just 'query' - but it should work.

The following queries for all documents with ID=1, and then filters to a particular Web. I guess your filter expression would be more complicated.

```
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(url))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPSiteDataQuery q = new SPSiteDataQuery();
                q.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Integer'>1</Value></Eq></Where>";
                q.Webs = "<Webs Scope='SiteCollection' />";
                q.Lists = "<Lists BaseType=\"1\" />";
                q.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='ID' /><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' />";

                DataTable table = web.GetSiteData(q);
                DataRow[] filteredRows = table.Select("WebId = '{282625A8-B13B-4DC0-B62E-D3255011FB5C}'");
                foreach (DataRow row in filteredRows)
                {
                    foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
                    {
                        string colData = string.Empty;
                        if (row[col] != null)
                        {
                            colData = row[col].ToString();
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", col.ColumnName, colData);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately complexity isn't the issue: When each site could contain up to 10000 items, post-fetch processing just isn't on the cards.

Comment: Then, sadly, I don't think it's possible using the SPSiteDataQuery.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll leave this question open for a while, and then mark your answer if there are no alternatives offered.

Answer (score 0):

You can add hidden field with SiteId to each list and use it in query.
Dont forget to set data to this field in event recievers.

[CrossListQueryInfo\SPSiteDataQuery how to skip items with specific WebId?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53149/crosslistqueryinfo-spsitedataquery-how-to-skip-items-with-specific-webid/55299#55299)