# CrossListQueryInfo\SPSiteDataQuery how to skip items with specific WebId?

Tags: caml-query, caml, spsitedataquery, crosslistqueryinfo

Customer wants to see 10 news items from all webs on front page.

Also customer wants to specify some news that we should skip.

I am trying to do next thing:

```
var id =1; 

<Neq><FieldRef Name=\"ID\" /><Value Type=\"Counter\">" + id + "</Value></Neq>
```

But this query will skip all news from all webs with id = 1. I need to specify in query from which Web i should skip news:

For example:

```
!(id = 1 and webid=someId)
```

How to write such caml query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can add hidden fields for SITE ID and WEB ID to list.

Then in events reciever set those values for each new created item.

```
 private void UpdateHiddenFields(SPListItem item)
    {
        if (item.ContentType.Name == "MyContentType")
        {
            try
            {
                this.EventFiringEnabled = false;

                if (item != null)
                {
                    var isSiteChanged = UpdateGuidField(item, Constants.Lists.News.Fields.HiddenNewsSiteGUID, item.Web.Site.ID);
                    var isWebChanged = UpdateGuidField(item, Constants.Lists.News.Fields.HiddenNewsWebGUID, item.Web.ID);

                    if (isWebChanged || isSiteChanged)
                    {
                        item.SystemUpdate();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LoggingService.WriteError(ex, "Cannot update hidden fields.");
            }
            finally
            {
                this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
            }
        }
    }

  private static bool UpdateGuidField(SPListItem item, string fieldName, Guid guidToSet)
        {
            if (item.Fields.ContainsField(fieldName))
            {
                var value = item[fieldName] as string;

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    item[fieldName] = guidToSet.ToString();
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    var guid = value.ToGuid();

                    if (!guid.HasValue || guid.Value != guidToSet)
                    {
                        item[fieldName] = guidToSet.ToString();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Then we can use those fields in query.

Answer (score 1):

Evgeny,

Seems to be a possible duplicate of this questions: 
[Is it possible to filter SPSiteDataQuery results by site?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34342/is-it-possible-to-filter-spsitedataquery-results-by-site)

Answer from the post:

> I don't think you can do this without some form of filtering post
>   fetch. However, it isn't hard.
>
> SPSiteDataQuery queries automatically include DataColumns in the
>   DataTable for ListId and WebId, so you could then filter your
>   DataTable by Web. I know it's not idea - 'query and filter', rather
>   than just 'query' - but it should work.
>
> The following queries for all documents with ID=1, and then filters to
>   a particular Web. I guess your filter expression would be more
>   complicated.
>
> ```
>     using (SPSite site = new SPSite(url))
>     {
>         using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
>         {
>             SPSiteDataQuery q = new SPSiteDataQuery();
>             q.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Integer'>1</Value></Eq></Where>";
>             q.Webs = "<Webs Scope='SiteCollection' />";
>             q.Lists = "<Lists BaseType=\"1\" />";
>             q.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='ID' /><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' />";
>
>             DataTable table = web.GetSiteData(q);
>             DataRow[] filteredRows = table.Select("WebId = '{282625A8-B13B-4DC0-B62E-D3255011FB5C}'");
>             foreach (DataRow row in filteredRows)
>             {
>                 foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
>                 {
>                     string colData = string.Empty;
>                     if (row[col] != null)
>                     {
>                         colData = row[col].ToString();
>                     }
>                     Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", col.ColumnName, colData);
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

Comment: i just get it that i can add hidden field with web id to news item and then use it in query.

Comment: how will you do it, if you have figured out - please post the answer on the forum, it may be helpful for others :)